# How To Use Manual Jobs In Github Workflow

Tags: gitlab, github-actions

**TL;DR;**

Our GitLab pipeline is triggered by new tag event. It has 4 stages. The first 2 steps are triggered by the event itself but 3rd step is manual. How to do the same in GitHub?

Hello,

I am migrating CI/CD processes from Gitlab to GitHub Actions. But I am stuck at one point and I need your opinions. I will explain the current implementation and the problem I am having.

In GitLab, after we create a tag, an automated script checks for linting rules, and if linting succeeded, an artifact is created. After that process, building an image from the artifact and deploying must be manually triggered. The image I uploaded will be self-explanatory.

1. Linting
2. Generate an Artifact
3. Manual Job
4. Automatically run if 3 is triggered and succeeded

[image: gitlab.ci]

Is there a way to simulate this in GitHub Actions? Your opinions will be really helpful to me.

Comment: You can use a [required review](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments) for that step.

Comment: Incidentally, have a look at [automated migrations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automated-migrations/automating-migration-with-github-actions-importer), they support GitLab.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks for your reply. I managed to do with your help :)